# symfony 1.4 sformextra autocomplete sort order

Tags: php, autocomplete, symfony-1.4

I'm using the jquery autocomplete plugin that comes with the symfony sfFormExtra plugin.

```
/*
* jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1
*
* Copyright (c) 2009 Jörn Zaefferer
*
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
*   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*
* Revision: $Id: jquery.autocomplete.js 15 2009-08-22 10:30:27Z joern.zaefferer $
*/
```

It does seem to sort json results according to the key, but I can't find any mention of sort options in the code.

I would like the results sorted like returned from the server.

The results are build like this

```
public function doMemberSelectForSelectById($q, $limit){

    $query = $this->retrieveMemberOrganisations($this->createUnrestrictedQuery('o'))->
      andWhere("o.name like '%".$q."%'")->
      orderBy("o.name")->
      limit(intval($limit));

    $org_data = $query->execute();
    $orgs = array();
    foreach ($org_data as $org){
        $orgs[$org->getId()] = $org->getName();
    }
    return $orgs;
}

$orgs = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Organisation')->
    doMemberSelectForSelectById($request->getParameter('q'), $request->getParameter('limit'));
echo $this->renderText(json_encode($orgs));
    }
return sfView::NONE;
```

The result in Chrome Dev Tools is (ordered by name)

```
{
    "1781": "1st Mechanical \/ 1st Maintenance",
    "1771": "Acco Building Ltd",
    "203": "Active Welding Limited",
    "443": "Aircon Commissioning & Services Ltd",
    "588": "Akon Electrical Engineering Limited",
    "625": "Alaska Interiors Ltd",
    "796": "Alutech Windows & Doors Ltd",
    "584": "Arrow International Ltd"....
}
```

The javascript that triggers it is here

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#autocomplete_rsvpCompany1").focus(function({
         jQuery(this).val('');});
             jQuery("#autocomplete_rsvpCompany1").autocomplete(
                 'http://www.nzgbc.org.nz/index.php?option=com_nzgbc_member&uri=%2Forganisation%2FjsonListMember%2Faction',
                 jQuery.extend({}, {
                     dataType: 'json',
                     minChars: 0,
                     delay:0,
             max:700,
                     scroll: true, 
                     parse: function(data) {
                 var parsed = [];
                 for (key in data) {
                             parsed[parsed.length] = { data: [ data[key], key ], value: data[key], result: data[key] };
                 }
                 return parsed;
                 }
         }, { })
        ).result(function(event, data) {
            jQuery('#rsvpCompany1').val(data[1]);
        });
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you add more information, like the result you gave to the autocompleter, the result the autocompleter send to the user. It's not very clear to me.

Comment: Have updated question with Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the "parse" method as follows:

```
parse: function(data) {
  var parsed = [];
  for (key in data) {
    parsed[parsed.length] = { 
      data: [ data[key], key ], 
      value: data[key], 
      result: data[key] 
    };
  }
  parsed.sort(function (a, b){
    var aKey = a.value;
    var bKey = b.value;
    return ((aKey < bKey) ? -1 : ((aKey > bKey) ? 1 : 0));
  });
  return parsed;
}
```

The problem is that the "data" array has a numeric key, so when you loop over the "data" elements in your "for" loop, you are adding the elements to the "parsed" array in the numeric order (eg.: 203, 443, 584, 588, etc.), so after adding all the elements to the "parsed" array you have to sort it by "data[key]", and not by "key".

Comment: Thanks - out of interest is there a way to force the key to be a string, even if it contains numbers?

Comment: In my opinion no, but I'm not 100% sure. Maybe you should add an alphabetic prefix to the all the keys (eg.: "1000" => "X1000"), but then you should also remove the prefix where you receive the request server side.